# I’m so scared and stuck

Tags: oaths, kaffarah

Assalamu alaikum warahmatullahi wabarakatuhu,

I’m really sorry, I’ve been posting mostly about Kaffarahs only because I’m really stuck and I’m not sure. Please let me know if this action requires one or more than one Kaffarahs. Someone made an oath and told that he wouldn’t mention a certain thing, but later mentioned it to an entire class. How many expiations does this person have to do? One or does it depend on the number of students? Also later the person mentions it to another group of people. Is this another Kaffarah to do?

I know that if you break an oath regarding one certain thing, it’s just one Kaffarah. But what if it’s regarding one certain thing, but you mentioned it to different people at different times.

So sorry. But Jazakallah khair.

Comment: It is better for you stop making oaths as Allah already warned us from their misuse making oaths in such a manner is also against the sunnah of the prophet(). My advice to you is stop making oaths at once, if anybody askes you tell him I'm not making oaths either you take my word or you leave it.

Comment: Use meaningful titles: the given title condamns the question to be closed as off-topic: as it expresses your feelings which are not the topic of this site and attract subjective answers! Also read [this advice](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1837/advice-for-writing-question-titles-on-islam-se) on our Meta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the oath is violated, it is dissolved and will no longer apply. Kaffara needs to be made only once.

> Allah has already ordained for you [Muslims] the dissolution of your
>   oaths. And Allah is your protector, and He is the Knowing, the Wise.

https://quran.com/66/2

> If a person swore an oath (or made a vow) then he broke that oath (or
>   vow), then that is the end of the matter; he only has to offer
>   expiation once, and whatever he does after that does not require any
>   expiation,

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/172210/he-swore-that-he-would-never-do-a-certain-thing-in-his-life-and-stipulated-that-he-would-fast-for-thirty-consecutive-days-if-he-did-it-and-if-he-did-not-fulfill-that-obligation-then-he-would-fast-for-sixty-consecutive-days-and-he-has-broken-his

Comment: So, if I broke an oath and did an expiation and after that I can break the same oath because it not there anymore?