# Exactly how much do I need to do?

Tags: oaths, kaffarah

Assalamu alaikum warahmatullahi wabarakatuhu,

Please let me know if this action requires one or more than one Kaffarahs. Someone made an oath and told that he wouldn’t mention a certain thing, but later mentioned it to an entire class. How many expiations does this person have to do? One or does it depend on the number of students? Also later the person mentions it to another group of people. Is this another Kaffarah to do?

I know that if you break an oath regarding one certain thing, it’s just one Kaffarah. But what if it’s regarding one certain thing, but you mentioned it to different people at different times.

And after expiation is the oath still there or do you still keep it as a secret?

So sorry. But Jazakallah khair.

Comment: How is it different from your [previous question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/55920/i-m-so-scared-and-stuck)?

Comment: It is almost the same (it’s edited a bit) but I would like an exact number or can you please answer “And after expiation is the oath still there or do you still keep it as a secret?”

Comment: The answer given in that question already makes it clear that oath can only be broken once because once it's broken, it is no longer applicable. So it isn't possible for an oath to require multiple  kaffarah.

Comment: @Crimson then this question is a duplicate and should either be marked as such or deleted by OP before an answer is posted. I'll do the first OP is free to delete or edit it in order to re-open it (if there's a necessity for that).

Comment: I know it’s a duplicate but I’m still not sure on what you are saying. Are you saying once an oath is broken and the Kaffarah is done. The oath is no longer there? Like I can break it again and not do a Kaffarah? Or is it still there?